# Change size of button

Tags: html, css, button

I have tried everything, but I cannot manage to make the button smaller in the width and height.

```css
.c--anim-btn span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.c--anim-btn,
.c-anim-btn {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.c--anim-btn {
  height: 64px;
  font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.c-anim-btn {
  margin-top: 0em;
}
.c--anim-btn:hover .c-anim-btn {
  margin-top: -4em;
}
```

```html
<!-- HINT: hover over button -->
<div class="c--anim-btn">
  <span class="c-anim-btn">
    First Text
  </span>
  <span>
    Second Text
  </span>
</div>
```

If someone please can tell me a solution, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS property of c--anim-btn class

```css
.c--anim-btn span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.c--anim-btn,
.c-anim-btn {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.c--anim-btn {
  height: 24px; /* change height */
  font: normal normal 700 1em/1.6em Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px; /* change width */
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.c-anim-btn {
  margin-top: 0em;
}
.c--anim-btn:hover .c-anim-btn {
  margin-top: -1.6em;
}
```

```html
<!-- HINT: hover over button -->
<div class="c--anim-btn">
  <span class="c-anim-btn">
    First Text
  </span>
  <span>
    Second Text
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad... check now

Comment: It works. Great. Is it possible to have padding instead of width and height?

Comment: I have tried to find solution for it, but doesn't work. Tricky!

Comment: only padding might not work in your approach.  as you are not showing full area, just a portion of it, i think you are gonna need them.

Comment: Ok, @reza. It's only this code I use, or the '.c--anim-btn' added in a button class to give it this styling.

Comment: did not get what you mean?

Comment: Sorry. So it's not possible to use padding in this example instead of width and height?

Comment: as far my knowledge says, nope can not work without width and height here.

Comment: @Musa my apologies, I was mistaken. You'll need to use height (when using `display: inline-block;`) but can omit width and use padding left/right. Setting a height allows the `<span>`s to overflow the `<div>` and hide the other text.

Comment: @hungerstar Great. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need to adjust line height and margin top after change height because of text seen. Comment out onn css please take a look .c--anim-btn and .c--anim-btn:hover

```css
.c--anim-btn span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.c--anim-btn, .c-anim-btn {
  transition: 0.3s;     
}

.c--anim-btn {
  height: 128px;
  font: normal normal 700 1em/8em Arial,sans-serif; /* 1em/8em means font-size/ line-height */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.c-anim-btn{
  margin-top: 0em;   
}

.c--anim-btn:hover .c-anim-btn{
  margin-top: -8em; /*Here you need to adjust after line-height change */
}
```

```html
<!-- HINT: hover over button -->
<div class="c--anim-btn">
  <span class="c-anim-btn">
First Text
  </span>
  <span>
Second Text
  </span>
</div>
```